# React JS- How to send the Date as LocalDateTime format instead of String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-form

In my React application, I am using react-Redux form.I have a datePicker field along with other fields.The issue I am facing here is the date is being passed in String format even though I am using moment.format().

My request param-

```
const initData = {
      createdTimestamp: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      otherParty: "",
      otherPartyName: ""
    };

<DatePicker
        {...input}
        dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD"
        selected={input.value ? moment(input.value) : null}
      />
```

The issue I am facing is with Date picker that whenever I try to change the date or try to click the Search button with the current date, it throws me error as the backend is expecting in LocalDateTime format. can someone let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: maybe LocalDateTime means it expects both Date and Time, like here: `2007-12-03T10:15:30.`

Comment: Right.If I send the static date like 2018-12-05T07:54:39.361, it works.

Comment: Then change format to ISO 8601 compliant or supplement the timestamp with time manually.